# Use react-query (useQuery) with Storybook getting error

Tags: javascript, reactjs, storybook, react-query

I am using storybook to develop my react components in isolation. I am running into an issue with using react-query (useQuery) with storybook. Implementing the component in the app, I get no errors and things work as expected.

```
async function searchStationsByCallLetter(_, param) {
  const request = {
    callLettersView: param, 
  };

  const { data } = await ApiService().makeApiCall(API_ENDPOINTS.BROADCAST_LINEUP.SEARCH_STATIONS, request, HTTP_POST);
  return data;
}

export default function useSearchStationsByCallLetter(inputValue = '') {
  return useQuery(['searchStationsByCallLetter', inputValue], searchStationsByCallLetter);
```

I have a custom react hook useSearchStationsByCallLetter that returns the useQuery hook. React-query should be using searchStationsByCallLetter as the api call. ApiService and makeApiCall are a custom axios setup.

The error I get in storybook is:

```
TypeError: Object(...) is not a function
    at _callee$ (AddLineupHooks.js:8)
    at tryCatch (runtime.js:63)
    at Generator.invoke [as _invoke] (runtime.js:293)
    at Generator.next (runtime.js:118)
    at asyncGeneratorStep (asyncToGenerator.js:3)
    at _next (asyncToGenerator.js:25)
    at asyncToGenerator.js:32
    at new Promise (<anonymous>)
    at Object.<anonymous> (asyncToGenerator.js:21)
    at Object.searchStationsByCallLetter [as queryFn] (AddLineupHooks.js:8)
```

Answer (score 0):

Probably mocking the Api request with a library as [msw](https://www.npmjs.com/package/msw) would help you get the custom response you may expect.

Comment: it's a bother to setup, but there's a mix of react query helpers and msw that can be used to setup queries in storybook: https://github.com/storybookjs/storybook/issues/12489#issuecomment-702958192